# How can I run ajax for an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, for-loop

I'm not sure if this is an efficient way to use ajax but I am looping through an array of information using a for loop:

**loadProfiles.js**

```
var tempString = "";
var searchPeople = function(sv){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
            tempString = xhttp.responseText;
            loadPeople(tempString, sv);
        }
    }

    var searchvalue = sv;
    searchvalue = searchvalue.join(" ");

    xhttp.open("GET", "php/searchProfiles.php?searchvalue=" + searchvalue, true);
    xhttp.send();
}

var loadPeople = function(people, sv){
    loadedPeople = [];
    var normList = people.split(",");
    var list = people.toLowerCase().split(",");
    list.splice(list.length - 1, 1);
    var zsearch = sv;
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        loadedImageId[i] = list[i].split("_")[1];
        if(loadedImageId[i] == 0){
            loadedImageId[i] = "images/GrayProfilePic.png";
        }
        else{///////////////////////////////////This is what I need to fix
            var grabPic = new XMLHttpRequest();
            grabPic.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(grabPic.readyState == 4 && grabPic.status == 200){
                    console.log("ready to go");
                    loadedImageId[i] = grabPic.responseText;
                    if(loadedImageId[i] == "Error1"){
                        loadedImageId[i] = "images/GrayProfilePic.png";
                    }
                }
            }

            grabPic.open("GET", "php/grabProfPics.php?imageid=" + loadedImageId[i], true);
            grabPic.send();
        }//////////////////////////////////////////////
        list[i] = list[i].split("_")[0];
        for(var j = 0; j < zsearch.length; j++){
            if(list[i].indexOf(zsearch[j]) > -1){
                if(loadedPeople.indexOf(list[i]) == -1){
                    if(loadedPeople.indexOf(normList[i].split("_")[0]) == -1){
                        loadedPeople.push(normList[i].split("_")[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(loadedPeople);
    console.log(loadedImageId);

}
```

**searchProfiles.php**

```
$query = "SELECT username, imageid FROM `memberHandler`";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die("Could not query");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo $row['username'] . "_" . $row['imageid'] . ",";
    }
```

**grabProfPics.php**

```
$query = "SELECT image, mime_type FROM memberProfilePictures WHERE `id`='$imageid'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        $imagesrc = $row['image'];
        $imagesrc = base64_encode($imagesrc);
        $imagetype = $row['mime_type'];

        echo "data:" . $imagetype . ";base64," . $imagesrc . "";
    }
    else{
        echo "Error1";
    }
```

However the server takes a moment to send it's return code, by which time the variable i in the for loop has long since been changed.  Is there a way to do this efficiently and update the array with new information based on what the current array value is?  I hope this question makes sense!  Thanks for the help =)

Basically I am trying to loop through the image id, and if the id is not zero(meaning they have already set an image for their profile-otherwise they haven't and the id is 0) then it will use ajax to connect to a database of images, grab the image that is relative to the specific ID, and then return the image source as well as update the array.  I am sorry I was not more specific in saying this before I just figured i could get away with a more simplified version.

Comment: It's not an efficient way to do it, you should follow another approach.

Comment: Your way of approaching this problem is fundamentally flawed. You're trying to do asynchronous stuff synchronously, but I think it's easily solved if you start using Promises to manage the async nature of the problem.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what it is you're trying to do, and what issues you're having?

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: Short of getting into an on-going discussion about what you *should* be doing, I'd say that you really should send all of the image ID's in one shot to your back-end script, update (do whatever with them) in one *go*, and send the response back. Iterating through the loop and creating a new `$.ajax()` request for each is redundant. Run the `for()` loop against the array, gather the appropriate ID's, send those to the back-end for (batch) processing. Then you can return the updated information which can be added to your array. This way you use a single `$.ajax()` instance.

Comment: But on that note, your *pseudo*-code is, well, *too* pseudo. Please provide some of your *actual* code. Otherwise, this will most likely get flagged as purely theoretical.

Comment: Alright thank you for your input =)  I will go ahead and just do everything server-side to avoid looping.  Ill upload my actual code

Comment: I have updated my actual code.   Now you can see where I have the fault at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Post Question Update:** I wrote this before your pasted all of your code. It still applies, but a few more thoughts:

- You seem to be just dumping data into SQL query strings. [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) would be proud, but you should worry about SQL injection.
- If you insist on writing the std `new XMLHttpRequest();` code yourself (and not use a library, like fetch or jquery), you should wrap that in a function(url,data,method,successCb,errorCb). Libraries will help.
- In your marked error code, here's the one that really bites you:

The `i` has long since moved on and doesn't match the index the call was used to make.

```
loadedImageId[i] = grabPic.responseText;
```

Moving on, original aysnc explanation:

#### Async Code

You're touching on how to handle general asynchronous tasks, which include ajax calls.

There are a host of ways to handle this problem, notably [callbacks](http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/javascript-callbacks/) and [promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/).

While you could do this in a synchronous way, for anything other than toys or quick hacks, favoring asynchronous data is best.

#### Example

First, define our service. In this case, it's not leaving our machine, but the principle would be the same. You send something (profile id) and get something back (profile image url).

```
// After ~1-2 seconds, answer the callback with the evenness of the input
var isEvenAjax = function(num,cb) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    var isEven = num % 2 === 0;
    cb(num + " is " + (isEven ? "Even" : "Odd"));
  },(Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 3) * 150);
};
```

You can have different signatures, but this is the crux. You put data into something, wait a while, and get a response.

For example:

```
isEvenAjax(2,console.log);
isEvenAjax(3,console.log);
isEvenAjax(7,console.log);
```

Could result in a feedback of:

```
"7 is Odd"
"2 is Even"
"3 is Odd"
```

And our test data:

```
var information = [
  10,11,12,
];
```

Now to send our data to the service and get something back. A simple foreach can handle this (NOTE: this is for simple demo purposes. This could get real messy real fast. Promises are a good way to go).

```
var getInformationResponses = function(information,cb) {
  var responses = [];
  information.forEach(function(i){
    isEvenAjax(i,function(response){
      console.log("Feedback for " + i + " is: " + response);
      responses.push({num:i,response:response});
      if (responses.length >= information.length){
        cb(responses);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Note that the function that wraps all of your asynchronous calls is itself asynchronous (and, under our callback style, it needs a 'done' callback).

Breaking this down:

After declaring a responses array (into which we put all the results), loop through all of the information elements:

```
var responses = [];
information.forEach(function(i){
```

For every element, make an async call.

```
isEvenAjax(i,function(response){
```

For the callback for every element (as in, when data is returned from the long running service), note with console.log (for demo) and push the results **and** the original data into the responses array. Maintaining the source data may not matter for all apps, but in some cases (like which profile ids correspond to which profile urls) it will. Recall: async calls will never guarantee order.

```
console.log("Feedback for " + i + " is: " + response);
responses.push({num:i,response:response});
```

Now, check if the number of responses match the requests. If not, then not all the results are in and do nothing. If so, then trigger the main callback and send the complete data back to the main caller.

```
if (responses.length >= information.length){
  cb(responses);
}
```

So an example like:

```
getInformationResponses(information,console.log);
```

can return something such as:

```
"Feedback for 10 is: 10 is Even"
"Feedback for 12 is: 12 is Even"
"Feedback for 11 is: 11 is Odd"
[[object Object] {
  num: 10,
  response: "10 is Even"
}, [object Object] {
  num: 12,
  response: "12 is Even"
}, [object Object] {
  num: 11,
  response: "11 is Odd"
}]
```

### Promises

This exercise is purely intended to explore how asynchronous calls can be handled and wouldn't do well in production. Problems like error handling (ajax calls *will* fail) aren't addressed here.

As mentioned by CallMeNorm, [promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) can be great. I don't have time to cover them now.

Comment: Thank you very helpful, I will have to look into promises and check it out as well.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands the example you have is going to throw some errors

`information[i]` does not have a `doAjaxstuff` method. However, what I think you're trying would be easily done with Promises which are native in modern browsers and even jquery 3.0 has a compliant implementation. In that case, you could do something like:

```
var promises = information.map(function(piece, index) {
    //doAjaxstuff must should return a promise 
    return Promise.resolve([index, doAjaxstuff(piece)]);
});

var inOrderPromises = promises.reduce(function(state, value) {
        return state[value[0], value[1]];
    }, []);
});

Promises.all(inOrderPromises)
.then(function(inOrderValues) {
   //doYourThing
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing it was *pseudo*-code, and that OP was aware that `doAjaxstuff()` is not a valid method.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry I was using `doAjaxStuff()` for the example.  Please see my update

Answer (score -1):

Ajax calls are asynchronous, which mean they will not wait for the for loop to finish. If you want to "pause" the iteration and only resume when the ajax call returns you have to set it synchronous.

You can do it by adding `async: false`

for more information check [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)